# Does Django pyodbc support Nexus DB or is it Database dependent?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-pyodbc, nexusdb

I have a project where i need to connect `Nexus DB` in a `Django` application. I have tried with `Django-pyodbc`,

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': "django_pyodbc",
    'HOST': "nexusdb@xxx.xxx.x.xx",
    'USER': "",
    'PASSWORD': "",
    'NAME': "testDB",
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': '{NexusDB V3.10 Driver}',
        'host_is_server': True,

    },
}
```

}

but failed to establish connection.

I have tried latest alpha release of `Django-pyodbc2.0.0a1` and `django-pyodbc-azure`, but found so many SQL Server specific issues. found that it is specific to`MS SQL Server` and `Microsoft azure Database`.

Does `pyodbc` on its own connect to `NexusDB`? If so, can it execute queries?

Does `Django-pyodbc` work correctly with a different ODBC driver?

Does `Django-pyodbc` support `Nexus DB`?

Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this ? Im trying to find a way to connect to Nexus with any kind of scripting language, the docs are not so helpful though

Comment: python with pyodbc and nexusdb odbcdriver you can do it. also php odbc connection you can use. and delphi as well

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `django-pyodbc` only supports MS SQL Server. It uses the underlying `pyodbc` package, but many of the mappings needed for the Django engine are SQL Server specific. The most up-to-date Django engine package for SQL Server is `django-pyodbc-azure`.

You may want to take a look at this list; the more popular databases are much more likely to have support in any web framework. https://db-engines.com/en/ranking

If you could use another database for Django's default database, you could use `pyodbc` on its own to pull data from your Nexus DB. I've done this before where I use PostgreSQL for Django, and make alternate connections to both SAS and SQL Server to grab data.